# Ucwords filter in angularjs throwing error

Tags: angularjs

Something strange is happening. Actually I am assigning a title from asynchronous call and I'm applying a `ucwords` filter on the title. It is giving me the proper output but throwing the error first and after then showing the proper value.

**HTML snippet:**

```
<h1 ng-show="defaultProduct.Campaign.title">{{ defaultProduct.Campaign.title | ucwords }}</h1>
```

**Filter Snippet**

```
app.filter("ucwords", function () {
    return function (input){
        input = input.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
            return letter.toUpperCase();
        });
        return input; 
    }    
})
```

Please note `defaultProduct.Campaign.title` is assigning from AJAX call. It initializes after ajax success. In my console it is throwing the error first and after ajax success call it is showing proper output.

If input is `show me first title` then output will be `Show Me First Title`. **But why it is throwing the error first** ? I'm thinking to use `$timeout` in filter but it would not a good way of doing that. Can anyone suggest me best way ?

**Below is the error** :

```
Error: input is undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> filters are evaluated on each digest cycle

Initially the value of `defaultProduct.Campaign.title` is not defined that is going to decide `async` call. At that time your custom filter is gets called before setting `defaultProduct.Campaign.title` value. Filter tries to `input.toLowerCase()` which return `input is undefined` where as input value is not defined. You should typically handle this scenarios inside your filter itself.

**Filter**

```
app.filter("ucwords", function () {
    return function (input){
        if(input) { //when input is defined the apply filter
           input = input.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
              return letter.toUpperCase();
           });
        }
        return input; 
    }    
})
```